# What's the maximum thrust-to-power ratio of the most possibly powerful absorbed x-ray?

Tags: x-rays

What's the maximum thrust-to-power ratio of the most possibly powerful absorbed x-ray?

In Newtons per watt..

Comment: Same as any other electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: @JohnDoty doesn't depend on energy? I mean, eg. gamma rays having more momentum than x-rays, etc.?

Comment: Per Joule it's the same. The scale factor is the speed of light.